# I cant see a problem but unexpected unindent occurs in my tkinter program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pymysql

```
def login():
    #clean
    Ename.delete(0,'end')
    Eage.delete(0,'end')
    Epswrd.delete(0,'end')
    Everpass.delete(0,'end')
    root.destroy()
    #/clean
    
    stem = Tk()
    stem.geometry("810x450")
    stem.resizable(0,0)
    stem.title("Log in")

    approve1 = ""
    approve2 = ""
    
    #function
        #player 1
    def player1():
        name1 = Ename1.get()
        pswrd1 = Epswrd1.get()
        
        if (name1 == "") or (pswrd1==""):
            messagebox.showinfo("Invalid", "Please enter a username or password")
        else:
            conn = mariadb.connect(
                user="root",password="",
                host="localhost",
                database="chessdatabase")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            #insert information 
            try:
                cur.execute("SELECT User,Password from players where User=?, and Password = ?",(name1,pswrd1))
                row = cur.fetchone()
                if row==None:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Error" , "Invalid User Name And Password")
                else:
                    approve1 = p1login
                    
                conn.commit()
        #/player 1
    #/function

    #display
    title1 = Label(stem, text="Touch-Move Tkinter Chess", font=("Colonna MT", 35))
    title1.place(x=140, y=40)

        #player 1 display
    name1 = Label(stem, text="Player 1", font=("Georgia", 13))
    name1.place(x=50, y=175)    

    Ename1 = Entry(stem, font=("Georgia", 11), width=17)
    Ename1.place(x=150, y=175)
```

The error occurs at the left side indent of `title1 = Label(stem, text="Touch-Move Tkinter Chess", font=("Colonna MT", 35))`, Why does it make "unexpected unindent" error?

I've encountered the same problem before but for some reason it was fixed. Sorry I'm new to python so I don't really know much about indents in programming

Comment: You don't have a `except` block for the `try` block.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you so much!! I didn't know "except" block was that important. Thanks! it is fixed now